# Getting an invalid cast exception when trying to order a list of objects with linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of tweets (class: SimpleTweet), which each have ID associated with them (x.ID where x is an object of class SimpleTweet). I'm using linq to sort this, using "OrderByDescending", but am getting an error on the line where I set a new object of type List(Of SimpleTweet) equal to the sorted list. The error I am getting is, "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[SimpleTweet,System.Int64]&#39; to type &#39;System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SimpleTweet]'".

The code:

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetTweetsByUserID(ByVal userID As Integer) As List(Of SimpleTweet)
        Dim result As New List(Of SimpleTweet)
        Dim urlTwitter As String = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name={0}&count=3"
        'Dim twitterfeed As String = utils.GetUserTwitterFeeds(userID, "docphin")
        Dim lq As New lqDFDataContext
        Dim var = lq.web_GetTweetsByUserID(userID).ToList()
        Dim sortedresult As New List(Of SimpleTweet)
        If Not var Is Nothing Then
            For Each twitterfeed In var

                Dim listURL As String = String.Format(urlTwitter, twitterFeed.TweeterFeed)

                Dim tweetXML As XmlDocument = utils.GetXMLForURL(listURL)

                Dim tweetnodelist As XmlNodeList = tweetXML.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes

                For Each node As XmlNode In tweetnodelist
                    Dim tweet As New SimpleTweet
                    tweet.CreatedAt = node.SelectSingleNode("created_at").InnerText
                    tweet.HTMLText = utils.ReturnTextWithHRefLink(node.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerText)
                    tweet.ID = node.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText
                    tweet.Name = node.SelectSingleNode("user/name").InnerText
                    tweet.ScreenName = node.SelectSingleNode("user/screen_name").InnerText
                    tweet.Text = node.SelectSingleNode("text").InnerText
                    tweet.UserID = node.SelectSingleNode("user/id").InnerText
                    tweet.ProfileImageURL = node.SelectSingleNode("user/profile_image_url_https").InnerText
                    result.Add(tweet)
                Next
            Next

        sortedresult = result.OrderByDescending(Function(tweet) tweet.ID)  
        End If
        Return sortedresult
    End Function
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to materialize the `result` with a call to `.ToList()`. Add it to the end of this line:

```
sortedresult = result.OrderByDescending(Function(tweet) tweet.ID)
```

`sortedResult` is of type `List(Of SimpleTweet)` and `OrderByDescending` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable(Of SimpleTweet)` that cannot automatically be cast to the expected type.

Comment: Thank you, @becksftw. I hope your first month on SO has been a pleasant experience. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to return a `List(Of SimpleTweet)` you need to call [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to create a new list from the `IEnumerable(Of SimpleTweet)`:

```
Return sortedresult.ToList()
```

`ToList`  forces an immediate query evaluation.